# Как запретить невалидные значения enum?

Tags: c#, json.net

Задумался вдруг о вопросе как десериализуется default(int) для enum'ов и обнаружил неприятное для себя поведение: Json.Net по умолчанию спокойно конвертирует и не падает с ошибкой.

Простой пример:

```
var data = "{ 'Sex': 0 }";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(data);
result.Dump();
```

Где класс и перечисление:

```
public class Person
{
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
}

public enum Sex
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
}
```

Никакого исключения не падает, на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять это поведение, чтобы Json.Net валидировал значения и падал?

Пока просто подавил проблему, у меня в проекте подключен [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) и добавил проверку на уровне уже после десериализации:

```
public class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Command>
{
    public CommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Person.Sex).IsInEnum();
    }
}
```

Но я что-то не уверен, что я буду постоянно пользоваться этой библиотекой, хочу обойтись только Json.Net

Comment: почему бы не `var data = "{ 'Sex': 'Male' }";` ?

Comment: Думаю можно сделать наследника _StringEnumConverter_ и в нём реализовать необходимое поведение. Но стоит ли (с точки зрения архитектуры)?

Comment: @tym32167 Гм, да, почему бы и нет? Почему-то думал что [javascript'овский enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287903/5752652) будет безопаснее на int'ах, чем на строках.

Comment: Как там жабаскрипт будет конвертить эти данные - это проблемы жабаскрипта. Сегодня это парсит js, завтра ts, послезавтра c# и blazor. Если ваше поле принимает четко ограниченный круг значений - то это и есть смысл enum и это желательно отразить в контракте между вашим бекендом и фронтендом или другими сервисами.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, можно так

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sex")]
    public string SexString
    {
        get => Sex.ToString();
        set
        {
            var sex = (Sex)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sex), value);
            if (sex <= 0 || (int)sex > 2)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка в значении, ааа!");
            }
            Sex = sex;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Да, это хорошо, видел [похожий вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190494/5752652) на en so. Но я тут задумался о том, что наверное надо было нормальные enum'ы в js делать как подсказали в первом комменте, а не с Int'ами возиться. Всё равно спасибо за вариант, я сам думал экспериментировать с StringEnumConverter (начало осталось в вопросе)

Answer (score 1):

Решил, что зря перемудрил с Int'ами и по совету @tym32167 вернулся к строкам:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = "{ 'Sex': 'Male' }";

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(data);
    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
}

public enum Sex
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
}
```